# Make Net::SSLeay with OpenSSL headers in non-standard directory

Tags: openssl, makefile

I am trying to install `Net::SSLeay` onto a Red Hat server with Perl 5.8.8 using:

```
perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=~/tmp/Net-SSLeay-1.65/lib/perl5/ LIB=~/tmp/Net-SSLeay-1.65/lib/perl5/
make test
make install
```

During the `make test` its gives me the following errors:

```
SSLeay.xs:163:25: error: openssl/err.h: No such file or directory
SSLeay.xs:164:27: error: openssl/lhash.h: No such file or directory
```

Now, I'm already well-aware that normally the solution would be do download `openssl-devel` (as many [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967961/compiling-netssl-for-strawberry-perl-openssl-ssl-h-no-such-file-or-director) here have pointed out) since that includes the header files. However, these headers files are actually already on the server in a non-default directory. I'm also not permitted to install any other outside packages on this system. With `Crypt::SSLeay`, I was able to use the `incpath` and `libpath` arguments to point to the correct directory, and it installed fine. However, it looks like these options are not available with `Net::SSLeay`.

How can I point MakeMaker to the correct directory so it can use the OpenSSL headers with making `Net::SSLeay`?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting [`OPENSSL_PREFIX`](https://github.com/rurban/Net-SSLeay/blob/master/README#L62) environment variable.

```bash
OPENSSL_PREFIX=/usr/local/opt/openssl@3.1 perl Makefile.PL
```